# Raspberry Pi wiping PW after reboot

Tags: ssh, vnc, password

So I recently invested in a raspberry pi 400 running up to date raspberry pi os. After numerous reboots whilst tinkering and setting up ssh/ vnc i followed the systems warning to change the default password from "raspberry" for security reasons (Note up until i finally changed my password the system rebooted and allowed ssh/ vnc without a hitch using pi and raspberry credentials).

After I change my password via GUI or raspi-config (I have tried both) to lets say "XYZ" the system succesfully changes the password and I can use ssh/ vnc with the credentials "pi" and "XYZ"

However this is where it gets confusing, if i reboot the system AFTER successfully changing and testing a new password, I can no longer use ssh or vnc with those new credentials. Furthermore to eliminate variables I have tried the default "pi" and "raspberry" credentials after reboot to see if the pw has reset but this also does not work. Instead I have to change the pw again through GUI or raspi-config and the cycle continues.

I fully appreciate the obvious answer is human error on my part, however I have done this a number of times with simple pw's or the default pw but to no avail and can assure anyone able to help this is not human error. It's almost like the system becomes passwordless after reboot.

I'm no expert and hope I have been clear and detailed as I am new here. If anyone is able to help I will gladly elaborate or provide further info in the hope I can get this fixed!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your sd card may have failed and gone read-only. Try a new sd card.

Comment: By coincedence I ordered some new SD's earlier so I'll give that a shot when they arrive later today. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can't say for sure what the issue was but it seemed to be software not hardware related. I was using the SD with raspberry pi os out the box and opted to wipe and re-write raspberyy pi os using raspberry pi imager on the same SD.

I then completed setup and changed the pw when first prompted and the system has changed and maintained the new pw, for now!

Seemed to be a bad write so simplest solution for anyone with the same issue is a fresh install to eliminate hardware issues. Either way thanks for the help!